# Oшибка с STL library и swappy

Tags: unity3d, stl, build-error

Я закончил работу над своим проектом и хотел его построить, но получал ошибки и пытался их решить самостоятельно, смотрел видео, искал другие решения своих проблем, но ничего мне не помогло. Я очень надеюсь, что умнейшее сообщество Stack Overflow поможет мне не потерять работу, спасибо! Итак, есть ошибка, которую я получил после сборки:

`[CXX1212] D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL [//games-frame-pacing/swappy] See the Console for details.`

в консоли у меня 2 ошибки, вот они

1 ошибка:

```
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1212] D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL [//games-frame-pacing/swappy]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2 ошибка:

```
Environment Variables:
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = 48835b4d1f5e342aefe5f016324d296a
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 23
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
USERDOMAIN = DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME = DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub
LOGONSERVER = \\DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_PROD = yyzPzalJDwrQcYNuOZam0bhKb26WyyhK
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
SESSIONNAME = Console
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = Ph-837Q6GNodAkyc2MRkxVPUcjlIET4d
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
windir = C:\Windows
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_DEV = 46b8b46515e7632fc42a504b72e05fd0
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
OS = Windows_NT
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = AMD64 Family 23 Model 96 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399
HOMEPATH = \Users\Acer
GIT_LFS_PATH = D:\Git LFS
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_31308_PNQPDKSUDYAHSRRJ
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 23
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
JAVA_HOME = D:\Unity\Hub\Editor\2023.2.9f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = DESKTOP-FKMNRR7
TEMP = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_YELLOWBUCKET_DEV = wKi8foVigDditGFvmZewRFWsEbX9Y0YO
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 3ded2a762163603391a425f688f990c8
PyCharm Community Edition = C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin;
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_REDBUCKET_PROD = ca12bb461ea96f9bdf5df4ded7d52994
VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE = 1
HOMEDRIVE = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21
USERNAME = Acer
OneDrive = C:\Users\Acer\OneDrive
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_YELLOWBUCKET_PROD = e03a9bbe92dc38a88cdb068d24c65b46
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_PROD = QqyoFpcWPi7V17p80_46CF6-sNGRGbHo
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 12
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_GREENBUCKET_DEV = 84H2gMm_FJzhr3mBaX1lM1JVukmCM7d9
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_DEV = client-wbjHYrmeSR87GmWOE7LDpf7sUySOIKHm
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_GREENBUCKET_PROD = c86fea37a9e1d3f0878b96e15b111c7c
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
TMP = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 6001
AMPLITUDE_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_RED_BUCKET_PROD = client-zH8Y7OK1i331EKuG77C6UxN8ygcM6LzS
AMPLITUDE_TOKEN_REDBUCKET_DEV = U4PSN7S7PuYVRODivvdcFwbu8R6IHGqa
SystemDrive = C:
AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa
OneDriveConsumer = C:\Users\Acer\OneDrive
SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017
HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662
APPDATA = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming
Path = C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;D:\Git\cmd;D:\Git LFS;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.3.2\bin;;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Acer\.dotnet\tools;D:\Git;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\Acer
WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3


stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1212] D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL [//games-frame-pacing/swappy]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
]
stdout[
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseApplicationId UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:analyticsRecordingRelease
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:collectReleaseDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:sdkReleaseDependencyData UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:writeReleaseSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

> Task :unityLibrary:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: D:\WinXGame2\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt release|arm64-v8a : com.google.prefab.api.NoMatchingLibraryException: No compatible library found for //games-frame-pacing/swappy. Rejected the following libraries:
18 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 16 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <c5ab5df75e57425eb4949046d4e04d0a>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Я работаю над своим проектом около 2 месяцев, и все эти ошибки появились у меня, когда я обновил Unity до версии 2023.2.9f1. Я не могу потерять свой проект, я этого не вынесу, пожалуйста, помогите мне, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйту "Optimized frame pacing" в Player settings проекта.
[Unity forum: Android Build Error: User is using a static STL but library requires a shared STL](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-build-error-user-is-using-a-static-stl-but-library-requires-a-shared-stl.1449946/#post-9088474)

Comment: ВОУ! Чувак ты лучший, реально. Я хочу пожелать тебе, всей твоей семье, всем твоим родным здоровья, счастья, и удачи! Ты реально крут! Эта ошибка была 1 из 7 коротые я решал 11 часов временни, и она оказалась последней, ты просто мой спаситель!!!

Comment: только есть всего 1 минус, у меня в игре теперь не больше 5 фпс, может это можно как-то пофиксить?

Comment: А всё, я решил эту проблему, теперь всё работает ИДЕАЛЬНО!!! Я ещё раз хочу поблагодарить тебя за всё, целую!